# How to subtract 3 days from current date for autofilter VBA

Tags: excel, vba, date, autofilter

I need to put a filter on dates in excel. The criteria is to subtract 3 days from the current date and it should show all the dates after or equal to. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong in the code below.

```
Sub filterTime()
Dim currDate as Date, oldDate as Date
currDate = Now
oldDate = currDate - 3

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$8722").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criterial:=_">=" & oldDate, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Yup I just changed it

Comment: Does it work now?

Comment: remove the `_` unless you have that line on two lines.  It tell vba to continue onto the next line.

Comment: No I changed the names when I copied it over and forgot

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: It says variable is not defined

Comment: Echoing @ScottCraner's comment, change `Criterial:=_`  to `Criteria1:=`. The underscore is a *line continuation* token, and MUST be preceded by a space, and followed by a new line. Note `Criteria1` is not `Criterial`. Named arguments must match the parameter names they're being supplied for. There's no `Criterial` (lowercase `L`).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon @Scott Craner I changed it to `ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$8722").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criteria1:=">=" & oldDate, Operator:=xlAnd` When I run it, it says object required for currDate

Comment: Something's not adding up, which line does it say "object required" for? I can't reproduce that problem with the code you have in the question. That said you don't need `currDate` at all, just do `oldDate = DateTime.DateAdd("d", -3, DateTime.Now)`, and I would try to avoid the implicit string conversion in the `Criteria1` argument, using the `Format` function to have an explicitly-specified string representation of the date.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon line 3 for `currDate = Now`

Comment: Try fully qualifying the `Now` property with the module it's declared in: `DateTime.Now`. I suspect you have something somewhere named `Now` and it's hiding/shadowing the standard library function. Then again, you don't need `currDate` (see previous comment)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Omg it works thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2):

Don't do math on `Date` values. The `DateTime` module provides `DateTime`-specific functions that make the `currDate` variable entirely redundant. Namely, the `DateAdd` function - made specifically for adding various "units of time" to a given `Date` value.

```
Dim filterDate As Date
filterDate = DateTime.DateAdd("d", -3, DateTime.Now)
```

Also, the `Date` value returned by `DateTime.Now` will contain a *time* portion that you probably don't want in your filter (if that's the case, then consider using `DateTime.Date` instead). By concatenating `">="` with a `Date` value, you are implicitly converting that `Date` to a `String`, and leaving it up to VBA to decide what that string representation looks like. Use the `Strings.Format` function to specify an explicit format for that string:

```
Dim filterCriteria As String
filterCriteria = ">=" & Strings.Format(filterDate,"mm/dd/yyyy")

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$8722").AutoFilter Field:=19, Criterial:=filterCriteria, Operator:=xlAnd
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed!